# change to newer Tcl/Tk version in R

Tags: r, path, version, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have multiple versions of tcl and tk installed in my tcl.framework and tk.framework 8.4, 8.5 and 8.6.

On top of this, I am using R and it is always complaining with the following error

> "In fun(...) : Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories:"

The multiple "directories" in which it looks are incorrect and it is not even the correct version it is looking for. What I would like to do is to tell R the correct "version" I want it to use and the "correct path" it should look for the tcl/tk files.

I was tempted to add a new directory to the R-Tcl/Tk search path with "addTclPath("/custom/TclTk/path")" but how do I tell it I want it to search to a different path and use "the new" version of tcl/tk from that moment.

I am using MACOSX 10.6.

Answer (score 1):

This is described in the R Installation and Administration Manual:

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Tcl_002fTk

The relevant section in R version 2.13.0 Patched (2011-04-19 r55523) begins with this.

> A.2.1 Tcl/Tk
>
> The tcltk package needs Tcl/Tk >= 8.4 installed: the sources are available at http://www.tcl.tk/. To specify the locations of the Tcl/Tk files you may need the configuration options . . .

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using an incomplete installation of Tk. Because Tk doesn't (by default) work as just a library, but a library with supporting script files, it needs to be installed correctly for it to function. Once you're using an installed version, that message should go away. (OTOH, OSX does include a proper build of Tk as a framework IIRC; a bit old, but correct. On my OSX machine, this configuration option would work: `--with-tk-config=/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/tkConfig.sh`)

Comment: I configured as you sugested, but when trying to run "make" I got the following error:

Comment: I configured it, running "make" I got the error: tkMacOSXBitmap.c:262: error: ‘CIconHandle’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tkMacOSXBitmap.c:262: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
tkMacOSXBitmap.c:262: error: for each function it appears in.)
tkMacOSXBitmap.c:262: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘resource’
tkMacOSXBitmap.c:263: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘DisposeCIcon’
tkMacOSXBitmap.c:263: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘resource’
make[3]: *** [tkMacOSXBitmap.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [build-tk] Error 2
make[1]: *** [tk] Error 2
make: *** [develop] Error 2

Comment: Are you using your own build or the system build? If the latter, you shouldn't have to compile Tk yourself. (That's the point of a system library.)